# Jquery after function is complete start next function

Tags: jquery, html, css, function

So making a "live chat example" and need to some 3 examples of businesses that could use live chat I need it so after the first function is complete to run the second etc...

I don't know if this is the best way to do it with a loop like below safe to say my jquery skills ain't that great. If someone could point me in the right direction or let me know the best way to do this that would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    chatOne();
    chatTwo();
    chatThree();
});

function chatOne() {
    $(".chat .topbar").removeClass("one two three");
    $(".textbox").slideUp(400);
    $(".textbox").delay(350).slideDown(400);
    $(".textbox div p").fadeOut(200);
    $(".chat .topbar").addClass("one");
    $(".topbar h1").html("Solar City Co");
    $(".chat .textbox p:nth-child(odd)").addClass("one");

    var textBox = ".chatOne p:nth-child";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        $(".wave").delay(4500).fadeIn(200);
        $(textBox + "(" + i + ")").delay(3500 * i).fadeIn(400, function() { scrollBot(); });
        $(".wave").delay(2300).fadeOut(200);
    }
}

function chatTwo() {
    $(".chat .topbar").removeClass("one two three");
    $(".textbox").slideUp(400);
    $(".textbox").delay(350).slideDown(400);
    $(".textbox div p").fadeOut(200);
    $(".chat .topbar").addClass("two");
    $(".topbar h1").html("Steves car repairs");
    $(".chat .textbox p:nth-child(odd)").addClass("two");

    var textBox = ".chatTwo p:nth-child";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        $(".wave").delay(4500).fadeIn(200);
        $(textBox + "(" + i + ")").delay(3500 * i).fadeIn(400, function() { scrollBot(); });
        $(".wave").delay(2300).fadeOut(200);
    }
}

function chatThree() {
    $(".chat .topbar").removeClass("one two three");
    $(".textbox").slideUp(400);
    $(".textbox").delay(350).slideDown(400);
    $(".textbox div p").fadeOut(200);
    $(".chat .topbar").addClass("three");
    $(".topbar h1").html("New York Fire Department");
    $(".chat .textbox p:nth-child(odd)").addClass("three");

    var textBox = ".chatThree p:nth-child";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        $(".wave").delay(4500).fadeIn(200);
        $(textBox + "(" + i + ")").delay(3500 * i).fadeIn(400, function() { scrollBot(); });
        $(".wave").delay(2300).fadeOut(200);
    }
}

function scrollBot() {
    $(".textbox").stop().animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $(".textbox")[0].scrollHeight
        },
        900
    );
}
```

https://codepen.io/nsmed/pen/eEeYva?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have a lot of delays, and that code will run async. That means that all your functions will fire after each other and after that the async delays will run when the time i in.

So I think the best way is to use jQuery.Deferred() object and return it when a function is finished. Then all your functions will wait and follow each other.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZOVPj?editors=0010)

```
function waitForEndOfChat(textBox) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

    (function rec(i) {
        if (i > 2) {  //Change the value here to increas the chat 
            console.log("end");
            dfd.resolve();
            return false;
        }

        $(".wave").delay(4500).fadeIn(200, function() {
            $(textBox + "(" + i + ")").delay(3500 * i).fadeIn(400, function() {
                scrollBot();
                $(".wave").delay(2300).fadeOut(200, function() {
                    rec(++i);
                });
            });
        });
        console.log(i);
    })(1);

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The so-called "Callback functions" can be implemented like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chatOne(chatTwo, chatThree);
});

function chatOne(callback, callback2) {
  // do stuff ... 

  callback(callback2);
}

function chatTwo(callback) {
 // do stuff ... 

  callback();
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k3061vyq/

Here I pass to the first function another function and its argument.

Comment: No real point in adding a fiddle if it doesnt show an example. Better off just adding your code.

Comment: I believe the example is in the "console.log()"s, as they show that the order of the functions is mantained.